# Blank screen with Google example of Google map v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I copied the code from google but I have a blank page... What did I do wrong ?
http://raidsnature.com/raidsnature/raidsnature.nsf/googlemap4

Thank you very much !

PS : "Google Maps API v3" is activated and the API key (activated on Apr 30, 2013 12:42 PM)  is the one which still works on my old page v2 : 
http://raidsnature.com/raidsnature/raidsnature.nsf/GoogleMap?OpenPage&Raid=1&Trail=1&CO=1

here is the code that doesn't work :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCklzGa0v5sp8cWNLXnEZph20tKa_rXups&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your map-canvas div doesn't have a size.  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+%5Bgoogle-maps-api-3%5D+map+doesn%27t+have+a+size

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the CSS part of Google's example, which (as geocodezip said) will define the map canvas size, but you also need to define `html` and `body` height.

To quote [Google's Hello World example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#HTML5):

```css
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map-canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
```

*This CSS declaration indicates that the map container  (named map-canvas) should take up 100% of the height of the HTML body. Note that we must specifically declare those percentages for `<body>` and `<html>` as well.*

Complete working example can be found at [Google Maps API docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple) (move to the second tab "JavaScript + HTML").